# Is it possible to teach Cortana simple macros?

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I've used Cortana a few times and actually think it's useful, for example for opening folders I don't want to have shortcuts for. Unfortunately she doesn't recognize folders or drives other than the default folders. Is it possible to teach her to define a custom drive as a path that Cortana recognizes under an alias? Or to have her perform a simple batch script when I give her a certain keyword? I guess I could have a shortcut to a batch script in the Start Menu, but that seems bothersome.

Comment: I don't think we can _teach_ her anything yet. Perhaps in the future they will add more features to her but she is quite limited right now. Personal assistants such as Siri, Google Now, and Cortana don't have much configurability.